# When is it useful to build a framework for Simulators only ? Or devices only?

Tags: swift, architecture, frameworks

In Xcode 7, Apple have made it even easier to build frameworks. Building against devices or simulators produces the following outcome.

[image]

Do we still need to use a script to lipo these together ? If so, my real questions is, when is it useful to have a framework that only works on devices and not simulators, or visa-versa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks that specifically deal with features only available on actual devices *might* make sense to only be available actual devices.

Two examples I can think of include anything that might want to use the camera or use BlueTooth.

Although realistically, since lots of testing happens on the simulator, it probably still makes sense to make your framework work for the simulator, even if it has limited functionality.

Comment: Has Apple made it simple to build a Universal Framework yet? Or do we still need to write scripts and lipo static libraries together?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow developers that use your framework to test/run the application in simulator, give them simulator/iDevice build (or universal). In my opinion, it's better if we support test in simulator cause we can do works more quickly.

Except that there is an API that is not available for simulator. In that case, we build only for iDevice.